# Database size of sqlite with flask alchemy getting larger and larger

Tags: sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask to make a project, I choose Flask-sqlalchemy to store data. Database is stored locally:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///manage.db'
```

I define one class:

```
class House(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'house'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    block: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(db.String, nullable=False)
    number: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(db.String, nullable=False)
    area: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(db.Integer)
```

When testing, I use for loop to add some records to this database:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    house= House(block='Springfield',number='8000',area=200)
    db.session.add(house)
db.session.commit()
```

after that loop, local file 'manage.db' size gets larger.
Then I delete all the records of the 'house' table:

```
db.session.query(House).delete()
db.session.commit()
```

Table 'house' now is empty, but why the local file 'manage.db' size haven't decreased?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting data in sqlite just marks that space as deleted but doesn't always actually clear the space and optimize the fize size based on it. See https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html